# when I want to put some code in question I ask I get an eeror ,but I can't resolve it?

Tags: insert

I want to put some code in my question but I get an error that I have to click control k and after it insert my code .I did but still I get an error.
where I have to put my code exactly between   or what else can you give me an example?
thanks 
johan

Answer (score 0):

Your paragraph where you want to insert to code should start with four characters of Shift + tilde (the character under the Esc) and at the end you have to put again four characters of Shift + tilde.